# Failed to create an editor. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-6.0

Failed to create an editor. the parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMxG0.png)

Script-Migration -From "PreviousMigration"

the Update Visual Studio Community 2022 From Version 17.8.6 to 17.9.0 is causing Error.

Script-Migration : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

At line:1 char:1

**SOLUTION:

I've tried to remove all temporary files form system folder for user and framework, but it didn't work for me, then I've downgraded to previous Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.6, and it works.

I've tried to remove all temporary files form system folder for user and framework, but it didn't work for me, then I've downgraded to previous Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.6, and it works.

Comment: As a workaround, you should try executing the [CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet) instead of the PM Console ones.

Comment: I am having the same issue since upgrading to 17.9.0. Also please note PM console commands already locks on to the project which is much easier than using CLI commands.

Comment: I am also getting this error since upgrading to 17.9.0.

Comment: Yep, rollback time.

Answer (score 5):

This bug will be fixed in 17.9.1, per the Visual Studio community site:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/sql-Files-cannot-be-opened/10584835

I'll update this answer once I verify it is squashed.

Edit: 17.9.1 has been released and script-migration now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug found in 17.9.0 , so Microsoft fixed it.

The newer version 17.9.1 now avaliable for Vsiaual Studio will enable you to open files and edit it using Ctrl+O.

So please update your Visual Studio to 17.9.1.This will help you to resolve the issue that I faced too.